# NestJS ConfigModule.forRoot load is not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, nest

I am trying to get the load env variable functionality to work in ConfigModule in NestJS.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [
        () => ({
          port: 3000,
          database: {
            host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
            port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10) || 5432,
          },
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I inspect process.env.port it is undefined. I have a feeling I am not understanding what this is actually doing. I thought it would be adding the env variable port and database. I think it may have something to do with expandable env variables which I don't understand how to access. Can someone explain how to get this to work and how to access these variables. The code above was taken from the NestJS documentation located at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as usual I answered my own question 15 minutes after I posted it. My assumption that this modified process.env was incorrect. It looks like it stores these values internally to the ConfigModule and they are accessible through the ConfigService.

```
this.configService.get<number>('port') // returns 3000

process.env.port // returns undefined
```

I will leave this up here if it helps someone else. You know what they say about assuming.

Thanks